Unable to tap on radio button using getByRole

I am trying to click Mozilla radio button with the help of getByRole checkbox
await expect(page.getByRole("radio", {name : " Mozilla"})).click()

Everytime I am getting the locator instead. Can anyone suggest what went wrong here?
await expect(page.getByRole("radio", {name : " Mozilla"})).click()


What's "Mozilla radio button"--can you share the page and a [mcve]? Please don't repeat things to bypass the filters--they're doing their job because this requires more detail. Thanks.
